# Android Studio multiple category app intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent, browser, kotlin

I want to create an alert dialog that can open the email app and the browser app. However, when I add two categories in my intent. it turns error. this is my code

```
val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(this@RegisterActivity)
alert.setTitle("CONFIRMATION")
alert.setMessage("Press Ok For Continue")
alert.setPositiveButton("OK",{dialog, which ->
      val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
      intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL)
      intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_BROWSER)
      startActivity(intent)
      dialog.dismiss()
      finish()
})
alert.show()
```

This is the error:

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER,android.intent.category.APP_EMAIL]
>   }

but when I remov `CATEGORY_APP_BROWSER`, it ran well.

Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: According to me both the category are the main application category so that in the one Intent you are not able to access both category at a time.

Comment: so,theres no possibillity for me to choose mail app or browser app?